# Communication from IdentityServer to API

Tags: duende-identity-server

I am currently building an identity server with Duende IdentityServer v6.1. I separated the identity server from my API into two different subdomains. People can register an account with the IdentityServer, but I also want some registration information to be saved to the API-database. So I want IdentityServer to be able to communicate to the API. Is this possible and if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is described in the documentation of IdentityServer: https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v6/tokens/internal/